# MD5 script. How to create a script if a md5check failes to retry the download script

Tags: md5

I got a script running for the downloading of the backups from my server.

The files are being checked by MD5 is they are both the same.

Here is my script:

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]] || [[ ! "$2" =~ ^[0-9\.]+$ ]] || [[ ! "$3" =~ ^[A-Z0-9]+$ ]]
then
   echo "Gebruik: backup_downloaden.sh jjjjmmdd ipadres naam"
   exit 1
fi

cd /home/backups/Servers

scp -i /home/backups/.ssh/dedecaan_backups backups@$2:$3-$1-0500.tgz.gpg .
scp -i /home/backups/.ssh/dedecaan_backups backups@$2:$3-$1-0500.tgz.gpg.md5 .
scp -i /home/backups/.ssh/dedecaan_backups backups@$2:$3-$1-0500.tgz.gpg.volledig .

date > $3-$1.log
ls -l $3-$1-* --time-style=long-iso >> $3-$1.log
md5sum.textutils -c $3-$1-0500.tgz.gpg.md5 >> $3-$1.log

scp -i /home/backups/.ssh/dedecaan_backups $3-$1.log backups@$2:$3-$1.log
# logs altijd ook naar de productieserver kopiëren
scp -i /home/backups/.ssh/dedecaan_backups $3-$1.log backups@85.17.173.168:$3-$1.log
```

I want if the check fails that the download job starts over again. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

let's take a look at the doc: `info coreutils 'md5sum invocation'` (as told from the man page `man md5sum`):

> --check'
>
> ```
>  Read file names and checksum information (not data) from each FILE
>  (or from stdin if no FILE was specified) and report whether the
>  checksums match the contents of the named files.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  If any listed file cannot be opened or read,
>  if any valid line has an MD5 checksum inconsistent with the
>  associated file, or if no valid line is found, `md5sum' exits with
>  nonzero status.  Otherwise, it exits successfully.
> ```

so basically, you need to check for the return value of `md5sum.textutils`, and go back to the beginning if the return value is not `0`. the return value of the last command executed is stored in `$?`.

Comment: Yes, backup will reveive a md5 from the server. and this file need to be the same as the backup. if it is correct it will download it. If it doesnt then the download will fail. if that happens I want a script that it downloads it again after some minuts. With an if statemant for example